# Open chat screen Skype from other app

Tags: android, skype, skypedeveloper

Developing an application, In which I have many user's account_id(skype id), Now what I want is to open chat screen of Skype (already installed in device) when I click particular User's skype_id from my application.

I did search on web but got no success 
Got the link how to start call on Skype but for chat?

[1) Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132556/how-to-start-a-skype-call-from-an-android-app)

[2) Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414494/launch-skype-from-the-app-programetically-pass-number-android/8844526#8844526)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Skype URI Scheme for this (Skype:echo123?chat).

You can find out more information about the URI Scheme here : https://dev.skype.com/skype-uri

Thanks

Allen Smith
Skype Developer Support Manager

Comment: Link is dead. What do I put exactly in the uri scheme? Is it possible to put a phone number there? Given a contact-id or a phone number, what should I put there? Can you please put an example?

Comment: @androiddeveloper you may want to refer this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2841708/1567675

Comment: @BharatDodeja How would you use it in Android code itself?

Comment: @androiddeveloper see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to open Skype chat conversation:

```
  private void openSkype(Context context) {

  // Make sure the Skype for Android client is installed
        if (!isSkypeClientInstalled(context)) {
            goToMarket(context);

            return;
        }

        final String mySkypeUri = "skype:echo123?chat";
                    // Create the Intent from our Skype URI.
                    Uri skypeUri = Uri.parse(mySkypeUri);
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, skypeUri);

                    // Restrict the Intent to being handled by the Skype for Android client only.
                myIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.skype.raider", "com.skype.raider.Main"));
                myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        try {
                    context.startActivity(myIntent);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
    }

/**
     * Determine whether the Skype for Android client is installed on this device.
     */
    public boolean isSkypeClientInstalled(Context myContext) {
        PackageManager myPackageMgr = myContext.getPackageManager();
        try {
            myPackageMgr.getPackageInfo("com.skype.raider", PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            return (false);
        }
        return (true);
    }

/**
     * Install the Skype client through the market: URI scheme.
     */
    public void goToMarket(Context myContext) {
        Uri marketUri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.skype.raider");
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, marketUri);
        myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        myContext.startActivity(myIntent);
    }
```

Comment: There is no parameter to go to a specific person's chat. It will just open the app this way.