# onclick to place call on Skype for business

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

onclick of an number should place a call in Skype for business
Tried using

```
<a href="skype:-skype-name-?chat">Start chat</a>
```

but this is redirecting to skype preview.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841676/how-to-start-skype-chat-not-call-with-link

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start skype chat not call with link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841676/how-to-start-skype-chat-not-call-with-link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This helped me:

`<a href= sip:{{:email}}>sample@sample.com</a>`
`<a href="tel:123456789">Open a Lync Window.</a>`
`<a href="sip:boss@boss.com">IM.</a>`

because Process name for skype for business is still lync.exe