# How to Open Skype Window With Message From Webpage?

Tags: php, html, skype-for-business

I am trying to open skype window with message. How is it possible to do that. I am able to open skype window with IM but not able to send messege.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841676/how-to-start-skype-chat-not-call-with-link

Comment: https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA99/how-do-i-add-contact-me-buttons-and-skype-uri-links-to-my-website-or-app

Answer (score 0):

At Skype they have a nice form ready for you to fill in. 
[Go to the Skype support page to start](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA99/how-do-i-add-contact-me-buttons-and-skype-uri-links-to-my-website-or-app)

Comment: By using this code (<a href="sip:test@domain.com">IM</a>) chat window is opening but I want send some text message here

Comment: Don’t know if they allow that..